# Error: Return outside of function. Not sure why

Tags: python

I am not sure what I did wrong here, can anyone help? I'm trying to write a function that sums up a list of numbers, and I also have a test function being used to test it. Unfortunately, the return function isn't working and I'm not sure why.

```
from cLibrary import test

def mysum(xs):
    """ Sum all the numbers in the list xs, and return the total. """
running_total = 0
for x in xs:
    running_total = running_total + x
return running_total

# Add tests like these to your test suite ...
test(mysum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 10)
test(mysum([1.25, 2.5, 1.75]) == 5.5)
test(mysum([1, -2, 3]) == 2)
test(mysum([ ]) == 0)
test(mysum(range(11)) == 55) # 11 is not included in the list.
```

Comment: You need to indent the body of the function.

Comment: This is the first thing you should have learned about Python -- indentation is critical.

Comment: add four spaces before return statement.

Comment: And all the lines before it

Comment: Except for the line starting with `def`

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar noted, you need to indent this properly:

```
from cLibrary import test

def mysum(xs):
    """ Sum all the numbers in the list xs, and return the total. """
    running_total = 0
    for x in xs:
        running_total = running_total + x
    return running_total

# Add tests like these to your test suite ...
test(mysum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 10)
test(mysum([1.25, 2.5, 1.75]) == 5.5)
test(mysum([1, -2, 3]) == 2)
test(mysum([ ]) == 0)
test(mysum(range(11)) == 55) # 11 is not included in the list.
```